# Lost formatting after saving

Tags: visual-editor, formatting

I make basic formatting to the text in visual editor. When saving, everything got lost, formatting, spaces, paragraph.... everything got inline...

I will go crazy !... why it's doing that ?.. i can make testing as request to gt out of this problem.. thanks in advance

the DB and WP got reinstalled, and is hosted on hostpapa. I have others client on iweb and those work fine. I have no choice now, to make it work on hostpapa, the migration to iweb will be the LAST thing of last resort !

i am using qtranslate, wich can be the plugin the bug the editor

Comment: Improve your question: Have you disabled all plugins and do you use TwentyEleven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research (2 day) i finally found a plaster... it's not a fix, but it make the editor work for most of the work. Here is the code to add to function.php of the theme:

```
function cbnet_tinymce_config( $init ) {
    $init['remove_linebreaks'] = false;
    $init['convert_newlines_to_brs'] = true;
    $init['remove_redundant_brs'] = false;
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'cbnet_tinymce_config');
```

and here is where i found it : [HERE](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-qtranslate-formatting-missing-in-editor)

Comment: Not perfect.... still remove a lot of linebreak and more.. but waiting for the fix...

Comment: Did you find any solution that works for WordPress 4.2.3?